# ObjectPool -> DontDestroyOnLoad or not?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object-pooling

I have a question while studying for UNITY

Which is better?

Setting the ObjectPool to "DontDestroyOnload".
and whenever scene is switched, return all active objects to the object pool.

or

Not setting the ObjectPool to "DontDestroyOnload".
Instead, whenever scene is switched, create a new object pool.

Or is there a better way??